# using ngOptions when using controller as

Tags: angularjs

He All,

I'm trying to use angular ngOptions along with a controllerAs option, and it's not working. what do I do wrong?

Thanks all in advance,
Chaim

my html is:

```
<body ng-app="root">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as tests">
        <select ng-options="test.name for test in tests.list">
        </select>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
     <script>
    angular.module("root",[])
        .controller("TestCtrl", function(){
            this.list=[
                {name:"a"},
                {name:"b"}
            ];
        });
</script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Your variable is named tests as is your controller alias. So it should perhaps be `test.name for test in tests.tests` instead of `tests.list`?

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Write it as an answer, it's correct.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I've changed it to list, still not working

Comment: Why don't you also try taking out list? Try just tests at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you haven't specified the obligatory `ng-model` property, like this:

```
<select ng-model="tests.selected" ng-options="test as test.name for test in tests.list">
</select>
```

and in your controller:

```
...
this.selected = this.list[0];
...
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/79yff62x/)

Answer (score 2):

`ng-options` [requires](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage) `ng-model` to be set on `<select>`:

```
<select ng-model="tests.selectedTest" ng-options="test.name for test in tests.list">
</select>
```